# Always be ready to give a reason for your hope (with citations)

Tags: discussion, moderation, close-reasons, deleted-questions

With only 2 mods left (and with all respect to Mason) only one that actively moderates the site.  Flag handling might be a bit off.

I'm probably going to have to delete more posts and leave less comments.  That means descending straight through eternal, divine, natural, and stackexchange law straight down through positive law to knee jerk reactions.

If you:

- say something untoward regarding another person or group
- don't have respectable citations (or any)
- appear to be spam
- use an abundance of rhetorical questions
- use caps for unnecessary emphasis
- use comments for chat

your post will be deleted, probably without any notice.

---

I'm sticking around for Jesus.  There may be souls that need an education and this place is one of the only places I can help tick off that all important Work of Mercy: Instruct the Ignorant.

Comment: Not ideal, but a very practical plan for such suboptimal times as we find ourselves in at present.

Comment: I respect your reasons for sticking around and I don't envy the task before you.

Comment: Now (and after the resignation post), I understand why that answer of mine was deleted so quickly.  True to say that a good standard and boundaries have to be maintained, but sad to see that it may come at the expense of some consideration.  I'm sure you have a life too. Looks like it's down to us also to not take offense too easily (which is "resting in the bosom of fools" anyway, as the Scripture goes, somewhere in Proverbs).

Answer (score 4):

I can see the difficulty in trying to deal with answer posts that have been flagged, given the lack of moderators who actively monitor what’s going on.  However, would it be helpful if participators paid more attention to questions that fall foul of the “rules” (such as inviting opinions or making claims that are not backed up by evidence) and down-voted them?  That way, dubious questions would be removed, perhaps even before opinion-based answers were posted.

Recently I’ve observed a load of new questions being posted by new participants where little to no research has been offered and/or where there is a clear bias that shows the person asking the question does not appear to understand even the most basic principles of Christian doctrine.  For example, this question doesn’t even seem (to me) to be about Christianity: [Do any denominations teach that humans exist before birth?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/75085/do-any-denominations-teach-that-humans-exist-before-birth)

Comment: The reason I didn’t answer the question by providing quotes/links from LDS literature about their beliefs regarding a pre-mortal life in the spirit realm is that the question nowhere suggested that was what was being asked.  In my view the question is still unclear, gives no evidence of research, and simply spouts an un-Christian view and invites opinions. That’s why I think questions like that should be deleted.

Comment: Denomination surveys are fine, especially if they ask something that Christians don't believe, that makes it very easy to answer! Problem with that question is it's really not quite clear enough and the OP doesn't want to make it more specific.

Answer (score 4):

#### We need to close more questions via community moderation ...

... and find out who will willingly and positively engage with the community here to get the questions in to stackable shape, and answers into stackable shape.

One thing I learned eventually on SEs: bad questions attract bad answers.

#### ... and then reopen the ones that do get recrafted into stackable shape

Let the rest be as dirt brushed from our sandals.