# Moderator deleting upvoted answer because it misses (quote) "superfluous information"

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-answer

Moderator Peter Turner just deleted my answer, with the following comment:

> Even though it's rather superfluous this question does ask for a Catholic answer. So you could at least address that

Note that he himself points out that this detail is, quote, "superfluous." I agree with that, because the question was based on a false premise, and answered by clarifying that false premise which had nothing to do with denominations (even though I would have been happy to address that). The deletion preceded the comment.

[The question is here](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/75440/why-did-the-jews-comment-that-jesus-was-not-yet-fifty-years-of-age/75442)

This behavior of a moderator is rather shocking. I can't comment, neither vote to undelete the answer.

Suggestions for improvements should be left as comments or edited in. The delete button is not meant to eliminate answers that miss superfluous details.

The deletion should be reversed. Following this, the answer can be improved according to the usual community-driven workflow.

In my option such abuse of moderator rights is detrimental to any online-community.

[image]

Comment: If I read the deletion notice correctly, the question was called superfluous and not the answer. Just add Catholic sources and ask it to be reopened.

Comment: Your image of the posted answer is missing the last statement. **What does the Catholic Church say about the expression `not yet fifty'as used by the Jews against Jesus?** This was not edited in, but was there from the original question as posted. Why does yours miss this point?

Comment: It is notable that 16 users (a lot for this site) voted up the answer which was deleted. Does this have any bearing on decisions to delete ?

Comment: @NigelJ   Consistency trumps popularity.   We've deleted and closed hundreds of popular questions from the infancy of the site.   Nobody loses rep from deleted questions and since it's not on the HNQ any more, there's little chance of it garnering any more rep.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, I should have said " it's superflous *that* this question asks for a Catholic answer".  But it's in the question, it's not hard to get something undeleted here,  I should have left a message to that effect.

Also, that question hit the Hot Network Queue, so it got extra attention by people who don't necessarily know or care that answers need to address the denominations in question.

However, I won't undelete the question unless you source it.  I probably should delete Nigel J's answer too, but at least he addresses the fact that the question is asking for a Catholic answer.

The real problem is probably that that question (and that questioner) consistently tack on "What does the Catholic Church say" as if the Catholic Church is going to have a different understanding of 1st century Judaism than others.

Double However, she might, so there it stands.

---

The fact is, this site's rather generous with letting people post pretty much whatever you want *until* a moderator sees it, possibly finds it needs improvement, and then removes it from view.  I should have put the longer version of the "please edit the answer and flag for undeletion"

read this

[Is there any plan in place to remedy the dearth of Moderators on this site?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6826/is-there-any-plan-in-place-to-remedy-the-dearth-of-moderators-on-this-site)

and this

[Always be ready to give a reason for your hope (with citations)](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/always-be-ready-to-give-a-reason-for-your-hope-with-citations)

for more information on the current state of this website

Comment: Yeah I understood you from the beginning. You called it superfluous that the question asks for a Catholic viewpoint, but still deleted the answer on those grounds. Yeah nah, I share the same feelings like others having posted here on meta and have lost interest in this community. I'm more likely to delete my account + answers than to restore anything at this point

Comment: @ig-dev so I was at a 3rd grade basketball game this morning, and the ref kept on calling the kids for travelling, double dribbling, and stepping on the line when inbounding (twice one time, so possession went back to the original team), I thought that was a bit too much consistency myself,  so I understand where you're coming from and respect your decision if you think this site is too up-ons in its ruleness.

Comment: I'm glad you understand my sentiment. The issue is that writing an answer comes at the cost of time and effort which the user is offering for free, and unlike the game, the rules are not part of a playful competition. So deleting a thoughtful answer is making the user pay double. If SE would pay me money to write answers, then the situation would be different, but actually they only make profits from it. I hope they pay you to be a mod, otherwise it sounds like some form of self-punishment

Comment: @ig nope, no payment, pure mortification.  Only getting pennies for the dollar stored up in Heaven.

Answer (score 2):

Believe that the right call was made. Catholic questions require a Catholic based response.

- Biblical quotes from appropriately approved translations of Sacred Scripture can be used.
- Catholic sources which include Canon Law, traditions, teachings and other sources may be used, but should be accompanied with appropriate sources and links.
- If no magisterial teaching can be found on a particular subject, the teachings of canonized saints or prominent Catholic theologians must be invoked.
- As a general rule, do not just quote Scriptures since interpretation can vary.

I think the above makes for a good response that requires a Catholic answer!

Comment: The issue is not if the answer could be improved or not. I'm happy to include relevant catholic information. But instead of commenting / downvoting, my answer was deleted in its entirety, including relevant content. In fact, you added the "catholic" tag to the question just now yourself, because that wasn't even there when I wrote my answer.

Comment: @ig-dev You are still free to edit your question and then flag it for a moderator to reopen it. Courage, my friend, I have success in it on at least one of my answers. As it stands it does not meet the requirements desired.

Comment: I'm not very encouraged by how this is handled, no matter if my answer remains deleted or not. Also, please don't call me your friend, I don't know you. `A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted` I will improve my answer when it is undeleted. Deleting user content for details that you yourself call "superfluous" is not acceptable.

Comment: @ig-dev Yes, I just added the **Catholicism**, but the question was already asking for a Catholic answer, which you should have been aware of.

Comment: @ig-dev I did not call your question **superfluous**! In fact, the moderator did not call your answer superfluous; the word in the closure statement is directed at the question and not the answer. Please read it carefully.

Comment: The moderator that deleted my answer called the *missing detail* superfluous. What I said is that deleting an answer for a superfluous detail is not acceptable

Comment: @ig-dev I see no proof of your last statement at all. Where is the statement including your **”missing detail”** found?

Comment: In the moderator's comment

Answer (score 2):

I think Ken's answer is exactly right, and I especially want to highlight that Peter's comment calls the question superfluous, not anything else. In other words, the answer seems obvious to him, and to you as well, merely by reading the story. However, the question is hoping for *Catholic* answers. Answering "catholic" appropriately on this site is, again, covered by Ken perfectly.

At this point, it's pretty simple what you have to do. Just gather some catholic sources and add them in, then flag for undeletion. Peter's reasonable and I'm sure he'll undelete it then. Maybe he was fast to delete and could have commented then waited for your response, but if your response was inaction, deletion would still have resulted. And since deletion is not permanent, we're really not in that different of a situation by taking this particular route to post improvement. Either way, the post must be improved.